# Is it possible to exclude parts of the matched string in preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

when writing a script that is supposed to download content from a specific div I was wondering if it is possible to skip some part of the pattern in such a way that it will not be included in the matching result.

examlple:

```
<?php

$html = '
<div class="items">
    <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 1
    </div>
    <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 2
    </div>
    <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 3
    </div>
</div>
';

preg_match_all('/<div class=\"item-s-([0-9]*?)\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/', $html, $match);
print_r($match);

/*

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 1
    </div>
            [1] => <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 2
    </div>
            [2] => <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 3
    </div>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [0] => 1827
        [1] => 1827
        [2] => 1827
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
  content 1

        [1] => 
  content 2

        [2] => 
  content 3

    )  ) */
```

Is it possible to omit class=\"item-s-([0-9]*?)\" In such a way that the result is not displayed in the $match variable?

Comment: What would the desired result be?

Comment: I would like to receive only "content 1, content 2, content 3". In each div class has a different number at the end item-s-xxxx and I would like to omit these numbers because they are not needed, however, in my formula it is necessary to the result

Comment: `$match[2]` should contain what you’re looking for

Comment: Yes. But in this case there are also $ match[0] and $ match[1]. I believe that this is unnecessary when matching

Comment: For example, I would like to use something like this in the expression: <div --skip this--> (. *) </ div>

Comment: @Wojtek Do the numbers after `item-s-` always consist of 4 digits?

Comment: Not always, sometimes they are longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can assert strings precede or follow your search string with positive lookbehinds / positive lookaheads. In the case of a lookbehind, the pattern must be of a fixed length which stands in conflict with your requirements. But fortunately there's a powerful alternative to that: You can make use of `\K` (keep text out of regex), see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php:

> `\K` can be used to reset the match start since PHP 5.2.4. For example, the patter `foo\Kbar` matches "foobar", but reports that it has matched "bar". The use of `\K` does not interfere with the setting of captured substrings. For example, when the pattern `(foo)\Kbar` matches "foobar", the first substring is still set to "foo".

So here's the regex (I made some additional changes to that), with `\K` and a positive lookahead:

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="item-s-[0-9]+">\s*\K[^<]*?(?=\s*<\/div>)/', $html, $match);
print_r($match);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => content 1
            [1] => content 2
            [2] => content 3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to parse HTML in PHP is to use [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to load the HTML and then [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search the result object.

**Update**

Modified based on comments to question so that `<div>` class names just have to begin with `item-s-`.

```
$html = '<div class="items">
    <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 1
    </div>
    <div class="item-s-18364">
      content 2
    </div>
    <div class="item-s-1827">
      content 3
    </div>
</div>';

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$divs = $xpath->query("//div[starts-with(@class,'item-s-')]");
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $values[] = trim($div->nodeValue);
}
print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => content 1 
    [1] => content 2
    [2] => content 3 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YDmRk)